# psql pairing of the same table

Tags: python, psql

I need to return a list from a table, pairing the rows exactly once; So if I were to have :

```
ID     NAME
01     Jones
02     Clay
03     Mark
04     Nancy
05     Larry
```

I need to pair them like this:

```
ID1    NAME1    ID2     NAME2
01     Jones    03      Mark
05     Larry    02      Clay
```

I can't just pair them in a desc order of the id, as the pairing is based on another table, showing how many times each have won, the problem at the moment is that I get pairs everyone pairing with everyone, how can I limit once a user was mentioned once in a pair, as 1 or 2, it can never be paired again?

As an addon to this question, how can I afterwards do something like :

IF exists without a pair [I do this by adding in another table that a person was pairless at one point] already, then redo query until person without a pair wasn't without a pair already. I know I can easily check results like this in code, but I must do it in psql all (I am using python, if that has anything to do with it);

```
CREATE TABLE tournaments ( id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(250) );

CREATE TABLE participates (id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, t_id INT NOT NULL, p_id INT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT fk_tournament FOREIGN KEY (t_id) REFERENCES tournaments (id), CONSTRAINT fk_player FOREIGN KEY (p_id) REFERENCES players (id));

CREATE TABLE players ( id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(250));

CREATE TABLE matches ( id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, round INT NOT NULL, p_one_id INT NOT NULL, p_two_id INT, CONSTRAINT fk_p_one_id FOREGN KEY (p_one_id) REFERENCES players (id), CONSTRAINT fk_p_two_id FOREIGN KEY (p_two_id) );

CREATE TABLE wins ( id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, m_id INT NOT NULL, p_id INT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT fk_m_id FOREIGN KEY (m_id) REFERENCES matches (id), CONSTRAINT fk_p_id FOREIGN KEY (p_id) REFERENCES players(id) );
```

Regarding the 'checking if one was already paired', I would check if they have wins with m_id = 0;

I do use psql.

Comment: Please post all relevant tables for your question?  As is, it's difficult to understand how you establish your grouping.  Also, which database are you using -- mysql or psql -- you've tagged both?

Comment: You'll need to include data too (`INSERT`s)